# Spring boot redirect loop

Tags: spring, redirect, spring-boot, while-loop

This project can be run in two ways to start: first,use the run debug Main.java: debug start, and then redirect loop;Second, debug by spring boot run  commandrun (use the spring-boot-maven-plugin startup),but no redirection loop. The environment is those:spring-boot-starter-parent ：1.2.3.RELEASE. How the whole?

```
 /*--------- FreeMarker Configuration -------**/    

@Bean
public FreeMarkerConfigurer freeMarkerConfigurer() {
    FreeMarkerConfigurer fmc = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
    fmc.setPreferFileSystemAccess(false);
    fmc.setTemplateLoaderPath("/WEB-INF/templates");

    Map<String, Object> variables = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    variables.put("base", contextPath);
    fmc.setFreemarkerVariables(variables);

    Properties settings = new Properties();
    settings.put("defaultEncoding","UTF-8");
    fmc.setFreemarkerSettings(settings);
    return fmc;
}

@Bean
public FreeMarkerViewResolver freeMarkerViewResolver() {
    FreeMarkerViewResolver fvr = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
    fvr.setCache(false);
    fvr.setPrefix("");
    fvr.setSuffix(".ftl");
    fvr.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    return fvr;
}

/*--------- Shiro  Configuration -------**/

private static Map<String, String> filterChainDefinitionMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

@Bean(name = "ShiroRealmImpl")
public ShiroDatabaseRealm getShiroRealm() {
    return new ShiroDatabaseRealm();
}

@Bean(name = "securityManager")
public DefaultWebSecurityManager getDefaultWebSecurityManager() {
    DefaultWebSecurityManager dwsm = new DefaultWebSecurityManager();
    dwsm.setRealm(getShiroRealm());
    dwsm.setCacheManager(getEhCacheManager());
    return dwsm;
}

@Bean(name = "shiroEhcacheManager")
public EhCacheManager getEhCacheManager() {
    EhCacheManager em = new EhCacheManager();
    em.setCacheManagerConfigFile("classpath:ehcache-shiro.xml");
    return em;
}

@Bean(name = "lifecycleBeanPostProcessor")
public LifecycleBeanPostProcessor getLifecycleBeanPostProcessor() {
    return new LifecycleBeanPostProcessor();
}

/**
 * 
 * @return
 */
@Bean
public AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor getAuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor() {
    AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor aasa = new AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor();
    aasa.setSecurityManager(getDefaultWebSecurityManager());
    return new AuthorizationAttributeSourceAdvisor();
}

@Bean(name = "shiroFilter")
public ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilter() {
    ShiroFilterFactoryBean shiroFilterFactoryBean = new ShiroFilterFactoryBean();
    shiroFilterFactoryBean.setSecurityManager(getDefaultWebSecurityManager());
    shiroFilterFactoryBean.setLoginUrl("/initlogin");
    shiroFilterFactoryBean.setUnauthorizedUrl("/login.jhtml");
    shiroFilterFactoryBean.setSuccessUrl("/admin/common/main");
    filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/admin/**", "authc");
    filterChainDefinitionMap.put("/api/**", "anon");
    shiroFilterFactoryBean.setFilterChainDefinitionMap(filterChainDefinitionMap);
    return shiroFilterFactoryBean;
}



/*--------- Mapping Handler -------**/

@RequestMapping(value={"/"})
private String home(){
        return "redirect:/admin/common/main";
}


@RequestMapping(value={"/admin/common/main"}, method={RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
private String main(){
    return "/admin/common/main";//main.ftl
}

@RequestMapping("/initlogin")
public String login(ModelMap model,HttpServletRequest request) {
    boolean isAuth = SecurityUtils.getSubject().isAuthenticated();
    if(isAuth){
        return "redirect:/admin/common/main.jhtml";
    }
    return "login";
}

@RequestMapping(value={"/login"}, method={RequestMethod.GET,RequestMethod.POST})
public String login(String username,String password,ModelMap model){
    boolean isAuth = SecurityUtils.getSubject().isAuthenticated();
    if(!isAuth){//
        String errorMsg = null;
        try{
            if(StringUtils.isEmpty(username) || StringUtils.isEmpty(password)){
                errorMsg = "admin.login.incorrectCredentials";
                model.addAttribute("msg", ApplicationSupport.getMessageByEnv(errorMsg));
            }else{
                UsernamePasswordToken token = new UsernamePasswordToken(username,DigestUtils.md5Hex(password));
                if (token!=null)
                    SecurityUtils.getSubject().login(token);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            return "login";
        }
        return "login";// I want to go redirect to login.ftl
    }
    //redirect to main.ftl  
    return "redirect:/admin/common/main.jhtml";
}
```

Comment: Is there an error ? What is the stacktrace ?

Comment: When I run application by right click option: debug Application.main,then open the chrome,input 127.0.0.1:8080/initlogin ,the chrome shows that:ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS,127.0.0.1 网页无法正常运作

127.0.0.1 将您重定向的次数过多。
尝试清除 Cookie.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS.

Comment: <configuration>
                    <jvmArguments>-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=localhost -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=5005</jvmArguments>
                </configuration>